# I need to insert a file to a VSIX in Post Build or Build

Tags: c#, vsix, post-build

I have a VS extension project, this extension use a lot of dlls and one of these dll install to a Chrome Driver a Chrome Extension, this chrome extension file needs to be placed in the same folder of the dll when the VSIX is installed, but, when I have copyed the file to the bin folder when I am building, but I can not put it in the VSIX File, I want some help to make a post build event to put a file in a ziped file, or something that I can set the chrome extension file in the VSIX build.

Comment: Set "Include in VSIX" ??

Comment: where I set it?

Comment: In the project file, or as a file property in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a bat file with 7zip commands to add the aditional files to my VSIX, and called this bat file from post build events, it works like a charm!